Why can't I use Xdebug in PhpStorm? I'm using PHP 8.1 and Xdebug 3.3
When I run Xdebug for my index page it gives me an error:
/bin/php -dxdebug.mode=debug -dxdebug.client_port=9003 -dxdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1 /var/www/html/thang/app/code/Smartosc/Thang/Controller/Index/Index.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action" not found in /var/www/html/thang/app/code/Smartosc/Thang/Controller/Index/Index.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/thang/app/code/Smartosc/Thang/Controller/Index/Index.php on line 5

Process finished with exit code 129 (interrupted by signal 1:SIGHUP)

My code in page index.php
<?php
namespace Smartosc\Thang\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $categoryCollectionFactory;
    protected $_category;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory $categoryCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->categoryCollectionFactory = $categoryCollectionFactory;
        $this->_category = $category;
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $categoryId = 5; // ID của danh mục bạn muốn hiển thị
        $category = $this->_category->load($categoryId);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($category->getData());
        echo "</pre>";
        $collection = $this->categoryCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addIdFilter([12,13]);
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(['name','include_in_menu']);
        $collection->load();
        foreach ($collection as $category) {
            echo "<pre>";
            $name = $category->getData('name');
            $includeInMenu = $category->getData('include_in_menu');
            $id = $category->getData('entity_id');
            if ($name !== null && $includeInMenu !== null) {
                $categoryData = [
                    'name' => $name,
                    'include_in_menu' => $includeInMenu,
                    'id'=>$id
                ];
                print_r($categoryData);
            }
            echo "</pre>";
        }
        echo "Hello World 33";
        exit;
    }
}

I tried running Composer commands, or checking the module again, but it didn't work. I want to know why it has this error even though my paths are correct and running on the web successfully.


That's a PHP error, not Xdebug or PhpStorm one. 2) The error is correct -- you are doing it wrong. You cannot debug/execute controller class directly -- because in this case the whole framework bootstrap logic/code is not executed (class loader in particular), hence PHP is unable to locate the parent \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action class. You should debug the URL instead.


I suggest you check the docs and go what JetBrains calls "Zero-config" path (listen for debug connection in the IDE and trigger the debug session via cookie with the help of  Xdebug browser extension) -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html
